In R, is there function that maps cities within a US county?
I'm trying to create a color coded map of the cities within Los Angeles county.
Yet the best I've been able to get is counties within California, but not cities with a county.
How could I create a color coded map of Los Angeles cities within Los Angeles county?
I'm using the maps package and trying to use the function map_data("county.fips")
